# How to pass client id and client secret to Application side(Mobile app, Web app) if application is supporting multi client login

Tags: api, authentication, architecture, basic-authentication, system-design

We have requirement of supporting multiple clients. Every client have their own set of users. Each user can login using their credentials (username, password). Login is done through OAuth2.
Each client has their own `client_id` and `client_secret`.

Each client will have their own api url. 
Eg - Client xyz api - xyz.example.com/api/ 
     Client abc api - abc.example.com/api/

Login request body

```
{
    "grant_type": "password",
    "client_id": "client_id",
    "client_secret": "client_secret",
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password"
}
```

Now the problem is how to validate the client and clients Api Url (Application side). Secondly, how to get the client id, client secret on client side(Mobile app, Web app) as login API needs these params for login validation. How can we pass client id from server to App side. Or the current approach is not good for the above mentioned usecase.

Eg - Similar usecase like Slack, which first identifies the workspace and validate it. Then provides login page where user login to that particular workspace using username and password.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may be using something like [Auth0](https://auth0.com) or [Authress](https://authress.io) for auth which can require fields like this. The steps would be:

1. Create clientId and secret and store it in the service client backend.
2. Ask logging in users for their username and password. Send these to the backend service.
3. Backend service takes all these fields and sends them to your authentication service to get back a JWT token.

To answer your explicit questions:

- Now the problem is how to validate the client and clients Api Url (Application side).
  You don't need to every validate your service clients, they are going to be validated by your auth server, and are your authentication to that server.
- Secondly, how to get the client id, client secret on client side(Mobile app, Web app) as login API needs these params for login validation. How can we pass client id from server to App side.

You should never send the client secret to the user's "client side" this exposes the secret to all users. Additionally you only ever need the clientId on the mobile app or web app side, and the recommendation is to hard code that value in the app.